# Updating table adapter config reference error

Tags: c#, sql, xsd

When I try to update a project that was written last year, I am running into problems.

I click configure on the xsd table adapter configuration and after my select statement I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sql.server.types, version = 11.0.0.0,
culture=neutral,publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91 or one of its dependencies.
```

What is odd to me is that I can do a preview of the data and see the sample select, but I can not do a configure from the gui.

I included the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
v. 10.0.0.0`

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.  Where can I find version 11 and why does the select work but not configure?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled/ repaired clr types and it fixed my problems....